# Coinbase balance 0.00089623 BTC help to get it out!

Tags: coinbase.com, dust

I have these satoshis won in Faucets, and I did not know that the commission was so high, it's worth more than all my work, help please !!!

Answer (score 1):

From memory it may be free (or cheaper) to send the bitcoins to another user's Coinbase.com account, so one option may be to get a friend to withdraw them for you when they withdraw their own balance. It's a lot of bother though for what's currently worth only about $5.

An alternative option (a better one, in my view) is to leave them there and hope that they increase in value or that the fees decrease, and instead spend your time on more productive activities.

Comment: I can't wait!!!!, I need it,I do n ot care if I lose some satoshis, someone who wants to receive them